# Plot using image() and annotate rows

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe (small similar example below), and I want to display the values in the matrix using image().
Firstly, it is plotting the columns starting with column 1 on the right and going from right to left, however, i would like it to plot with column 1 on the left and then going from left to right.

Secondly, I would like to add a 'colour strip' to the plot indicating that rows 1 and 2 have the same $taxid, and that rows 3 and 4 have the same $taxid. Similar to "ColSideColors" in heatmap.

Any suggestions?

thank you

```
df<-data.frame(taxid=c("A","A","B","B"),c2=c(1,2,3,4),c3=c(3,4,5,6))
nr<-dim(df)[1]
nc<-dim(df)[2]
z<-as.matrix(log(df[,2:3]))
image(x=1:nc, y=1:nr, z=t(z), axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE)
```

Okay, I have now decided to try and make a 'skinny' barplot for the colorstip.  However, it is not 'stacking' the barplot (although by height is a vector, and beside=FALSE.  Therefore when I combine them using layout it complains about not having big enough margins.

Any help on stacking the barplot, or other more sophisticated solutions.
thanks

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2),1,2,byrow=FALSE),heights=c(1,1),widths=c(1,9))
barplot(as.vector(table(df$taxid)),width=0.1,beside=FALSE,col=rainbow(length(table(df$taxid))))
image(x=1:nc, y=1:nr, z=t(z), axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE)
```

Comment: Check answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10124180/1183242

Comment: Specifically, as regards to your first problem, if you don't like the ordering of the columns in the image, reorder the columns of your matrix to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rasterImage` function to add color bands to an existing plot:

```
tmp <- as.raster(  rev(c('#00ff00','#0000ff')[df$taxid]) ) 
par(xpd=NA)
rasterImage( tmp, 3, 0.5, 3.1, 4.5, interpolate=FALSE)
```

If you don't have the rasterImage option then you can overlay 2 image plots.  Below I add 2 columns of NA to the original matrix and expand the `x=` argument so that a small blank space is added to the right, then I create a new matrix with the taxid information in only the 4th column (all others NA) and use it with the same `x=` but with `add=TRUE` so that it creates the new image plot on top of the old (but only adds color in the previously blank area and does not overplot the image of interest because those values are NA).

```
z2 <- cbind(z, NA, NA)
image(x=c(1:3,3.05, 3.1), y=1:nr, z=t(z2), axes=FALSE)

z3 <- cbind(NA,NA,NA, as.numeric(df$taxid))
image(x=c(1:3,3.05, 3.1), y=1:nr, z=t(z3), add=TRUE, col=c('#00ff00','#0000ff'))
```

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 2.9.1 (2009-06-26)
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

locale:
LC_CTYPE=en_US;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US;LC_COLLATE=en_US;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=en_US;LC_PAPER=en_US;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.9.1
> ?as.raster
No documentation for 'as.raster' in specified packages and libraries:
you could try '??as.raster'

Comment: Thanks, but we have an old version of R (2.9.1) installed on our system, and it looks like as.raster is only available in more recent versions of grDevices.  Until our version of R is updated, can this be done with any base commands?  Thank you.

Comment: Added example using only `image` function.